# Breaking phrase every 100 positions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to include a line break "
" to 100 characters, however, can not break words, if the letter is possição I break in near space, how can I do this?
The phrase is about 300 characters.

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase this? Give more detail, provide sample data, expected output, that kind of thing...

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Here is another good one to look at. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: This sounds like the kind of display formatting that generally belongs in an application, not in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take 100 characters from the [start of the string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)
2. [Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) it
3. [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) the first space
4. Calculate the break position from the start of the string using the results from step 3.
5. If more than 100 characters left, repeat from step 1.

Comment: Weird how sql server doesnt have reverse string search. [**Here**](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/sql/t-sql/charindex-reverse-find-occurrence-starting-from-end-of-string-in-tsql.html) is a blog with more detail.